# Combining two css pseudo class

Tags: html, css, hover, pseudo-class

What I am trying to do is, I want to color the hovered link with white color and all the unhovered link grey, whenever a link is hover. Can I achieve this using pure css?

and I have tried:

```
#nav-links a:hover #nav-links a:not(:hover){color:grey; }
```

my codepen link is:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/mdfarzan/pen/YzpXvmb?editors=1100)

Comment: This might help you: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/OJbyWrW

Comment: Thanks man. I did not think it can so easy :)